# function to remove object properties from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

In JS;

Trying to write a function that takes in an array of objects and a series of arguments. The function will remove any properties not given as arguments.

example:
input
cleanseData([{a: 'b', c:'d'}, {a: 'q'}], 'a');

output
[{a: 'b'}, {a: 'q'}]

Here is the function that tried but the objects remain unchanged.

```
var cleanseData = function(listObj, key1, key2, key3) {
    for (var i=0; i<listObj.length; i++) {
        for(k in listObj[i]) {
            if(k !== key1 && k!==key2 && k!==key3) {
            delete listObj[i].k;
            }
        }
    }
    return listObj;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? What error is it?

Comment: It might be simpler to convert arguments 1 to n to an array called say *keys*, then you could do something like `if (keys.indexOf(k) == -1) {/* delete key */}`. But you need a *hasOwnProperty* test to exclude inherited properties, or use [*Object.keys*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14). You might also have issues with `!==` given that keys are always strings and you might provide numbers as arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line...

```
delete listObj[i].k;
```

It's trying to delete a property `k`, which doesn't exist. Change to...

```
delete listObj[i][k];
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ljcumzz/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var cleanseData = function (listObj,key) {
    for (var i = 0;i < listObj.length; i++) {
        for(var k in listObj[i])
        if (k!=key) {
            delete listObj[i][k];
        }
    }
    return listObj;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(cleanseData([{a: 'b', c:'d'}, {a: 'q'}], 'a')));
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/euud4nau/)

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of style, you could do something like this

```
function cleanse(arr, proplist) {
  return arr.map(function(elem) {
     var props = Object.keys(elem);
     var props_to_remove = props.filter(function(p) {
      return proplist.indexOf(p) === -1;
     }); 
     props_to_remove.forEach(function(p) {
         delete elem[p];
     })
     return elem;
    });
}
```

Note that this returns a new array which satisfies your condition and does not modify the old array you passed in.